# jquery fadeToggle not working on echoed script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a div whose contents are retrieved asynch by $.post().
The contents retrieved are multiple images each with seperate ids.
I want each of the images to fadeToggle on hover()

So i calculate image id in my php on the spot, generate the image and add a jquery handler
and echo back the results:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("<?php echo '#'.$postid.'image'; ?>").hover(function()
            {
                $(this).fadeToggle("fast");
            },
            function()
            {
                $(this).fadeToggle("fast");
            });

    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="<?php echo $postid; ?>" class="post_box" > 
<img src="<?php echo '/way2tweek'.$path.$name; ?>" width="500" class="img_get"   
draggable="false" alt="<?php echo $postid; ?>" id="<?php echo $postid.'image'; ?>">
<div class="imageproperty" id="<?php echo $postid.'props'?>">

</div>
</div>
```

on the page images are received. scripts are received. the calculated ids match but the images are not fadeToggled. No Console debug message too. Please help.

Comment: if you'd post your HTML, it would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

You have both the hash and the dot in your PHP-generated selector:

```
<?php echo '#'.$postid.'.image'; ?>
```

produces a string like

```
#mypostid.image
```

I don't know your HTML structure, but you may want the selector to be `#mypostid .image` (note the space), so:

```
<?php echo '#'.$postid.' .image'; ?>
```

Comment: I rectified and replaced the .image to image but still its not working.

Comment: Is the image initially hidden?